# How to call a bash script from php passing parameters

Tags: php, parameters, exec

I have a php script that execute a bash script. I try to pass parameters like this:

```
$script="/opt/lampp/htdocs/adapt.sh"
$file="/opt/lampp/htdocs/videos/video1.mp4"
$prefix="Test"

exec ('.$script.' '.$file.' '.$prefix.');
```

What's wrong? How can I pass the parameters?

Comment: You can already spot what is wrong by just looking on how your syntax is highlighted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your dots in the wrong place, should read:

```
exec ( $script . ' ' . $file . ' ' . $prefix );
```

or more readable

```
exec( "$script $file $prefix" );
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand what your question is, but your exec() call should look like this:

```
exec ($script.' '.$file.' '.$prefix);
```

If you accept parameters from outside (e.g. from a GET or POST parameter), be sure to use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on the arguments for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong:

```
exec ('.$script.' '.$file.' '.$prefix.');
```

be carefull with quotes :-)

```
exec ($script.' '.$file.' '.$prefix);
```